# How do I make a text be delayed after a question mark? (Unity)

Tags: c#, text, delay, coroutine, ienumerator

I have this text with a typewriter effect and want it to have a bigger delay after a question mark. I have another code that works with commas and periods but that because I copied it. I tried making my own for only the question marks in order to have them apply a larger delay but unfortunately it doesn't work. Would really appreciate some help! ( i know there could be some things that don't make sense there but I just tried them )

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Text;
using System;



public class QuestionMarkDelay : MonoBehaviour
{

    private char questionMark;
    private bool lastCharQuestion;
    public float delayAfterQuestion = 1.2f;
    private string story;
    public Text text;
    
    

    
    void Start()
    {
        questionMark = Convert.ToChar(63);
      
        
    }

    public void ChangeText(string textContent, float delayAfterQuestion = 5f)
    {
        StopCoroutine(PlayText()); //stop Coroutime if exist
        story = textContent;
        text.text = ""; //clean text
        Invoke("Start_PlayText", delayAfterQuestion); //Invoke effect
    }


    void Start_PlayText()
    {
        StartCoroutine(PlayText());
    }

    IEnumerator PlayText()
    {
       
        
        foreach (char b in story)
        {
            
            if (lastCharQuestion)
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(delayAfterQuestion);
                lastCharQuestion = false;
            }
            if (b == questionMark)
            {
                lastCharQuestion = true;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT** :

```
public void ChangeText(string textContent, float delayBetweenChars = 0f)
    {
        StopCoroutine(PlayText()); //stop Coroutime if exist
        story = textContent;
        text.text = ""; //clean text
        Invoke("Start_PlayText", delayBetweenChars); //Invoke effect
    }
```

Comment: Why `questionMark = Convert.ToChar(63)`.  Why not just declare `private const char QuestionMark = '?';`

Comment: The code I took used this method so I went with it. Didn't even know how to declare "?" like that.

Comment: If you use a single quote, it's a `char`, double-quotes delimiter strings

Comment: Is there some code (not shown) in `PlayText` that actually displays the characters? Why the complication of `lastCharQuestion`? Why not just delay after you "play" the question mark immediately?

Comment: @Flydog57 i know I just put ? between double quotes to refer to the question mark.

Comment: @NetMage actually i just took that from the other script that also contained this (check ** edit in post). and how exactly can I just delay after "playing" the question mark? that is what i tried to do but as you can see I failed miserably.

Comment: I don't see where you output the text: you seem to be missing `text.text += b;`?

Comment: If you want a string, you can say `const string QuestionString = "?";` (within double quotes); if you want a character, it's `const char QuestionChar = '?';` (within single quotes).

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: You need to have one `PlayText` routine with all delays for all characters.

Try this:

```
IEnumerator PlayText() {
    foreach (char b in story) {
        text.text += b;

        float charDelay = delayBetweenChars;
        switch (b) {
            case '?':
                charDelay = delayAfterQuestion;
                break;
            case ',':
                charDelay = delayAfterComma;
                break;
            case '.':
                charDelay = delayAfterPeriod;
                break;
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delayAfterQuestion);
    }
}
```